# how to save created objects in GTA SAMP?

Tags: pawn

I'm writing code in Pawn language in visual studio. I can create an object, but how can I save it so that the player can later see a list of created objects?

I need to add a command for example /list - where a dialog box like DIALOG_STYLE_TABLIST_HEADERS will open, and information about the created objects will be displayed as: "Name" "Object ID" "Who created the object (Nickname)"

I have this code:

```
#include <a_samp>

#define DIALOG_SOE          1050
#define DIALOG_CREATE       DIALOG_SOE + 1
#define DIALOG_SELECT       DIALOG_SOE + 2
#define DIALOG_TUTORIAL     DIALOG_SOE + 3
#define DIALOG_SAVE_1       DIALOG_SOE + 4
#define DIALOG_SAVE_2       DIALOG_SOE + 5

enum SavedEnums {
    Float:foX,
    Float:foY,
    Float:foZ,
    Float:roX,
    Float:roY,
    Float:roZ
};

new O[SavedEnums];

public OnPlayerCommandText(playerid, cmdtext[])
{
    if(strcmp("/soe", cmdtext, true, 10) == 0)
    {
        if(0 == IsPlayerAdmin(playerid))
            return 1;

        ShowPlayerDialog(playerid, DIALOG_SOE, DIALOG_STYLE_LIST, "Object Editor", \
        "Instructions\nCreate Object\nEdit Map","Select","Cancel");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

public OnDialogResponse(playerid, dialogid, response, listitem, inputtext[])
{
    switch(dialogid)
    {
        case DIALOG_SOE:
        {
            if(response)
            {
                if(listitem == 0) ShowPlayerDialog(playerid, DIALOG_TUTORIAL, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX, \
                "Instructions","{FFFFFF}Hotkeys:\n\n{008080}Escape {FFFFFF}- to exit the editor or select an object\n{008080}Shift {FFFFFF}- to rotate the camera\nwhile editing",\
                "Done","Back");
                if(listitem == 1) ShowPlayerDialog(playerid, DIALOG_CREATE, DIALOG_STYLE_INPUT, \
                "Create Object","Enter the model ID of the object to create it\nThe object will appear in front of you, and you can then modify it\n\nMaximum object ID - 19469",\
                "Create","Back");
                if(listitem == 2) SelectObject(playerid);
            }
        }
        case DIALOG_CREATE:
        {
            if(!response) return OnPlayerCommandText(playerid, "/soe");
            if(!strval(inputtext)) return ShowPlayerDialog(playerid, DIALOG_CREATE, DIALOG_STYLE_INPUT, \
            "Create Object","Enter the model ID of the object to create it\nThe object will appear in front of you, and you can then modify it\n\nMaximum object ID - 19469\n{FF0000}Error: Invalid value!",\
            "Create","Back");
            new Float:X, Float:Y, Float:Z;
            GetPlayerPos(playerid, X, Y, Z);
            new obj;
            obj = CreateObject(strval(inputtext), X+1, Y+1, Z+1, 0.0,0.0,0.0);
            EditObject(playerid, obj);
            SetPVarInt(playerid, "ModelID", strval(inputtext));
        }
        case DIALOG_SELECT:
        {
            new objectid = GetPVarInt(playerid, "SelectedObject");
            if(response) EditObject(playerid, objectid);
            else DestroyObject(objectid) && CancelEdit(playerid);
        }
        case DIALOG_TUTORIAL: if(!response) return OnPlayerCommandText(playerid, "/soe");
        case DIALOG_SAVE_1:
        {
            if(response) return ShowPlayerDialog(playerid, DIALOG_SAVE_2, DIALOG_STYLE_INPUT, "File Name","Enter the name of the text document\nwhere your object will be saved","Save","Cancel");
        }
        case DIALOG_SAVE_2:
        {
            if(response)
            {
                if(!strlen(inputtext)) return SendClientMessage(playerid, 0xFF0000FF, "You left the input field empty!");
                new string1[255], string2[128], File: objs;
                format(string2, sizeof(string2), "soe/%s.txt", inputtext);
                objs = fopen(string2, io_append);
                format(string1, sizeof(string1), "CreateObject(%d, %f,%f,%f, %f,%f,%f);\r\n", \
                GetPVarInt(playerid, "ModelID"), O[foX],O[foY],O[foZ], O[roX],O[roY],O[roZ]);
                fwrite(objs, string1);
                fclose(objs);
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

public OnPlayerSelectObject(playerid, type, objectid, modelid, Float:fX, Float:fY, Float:fZ)
{
    ShowPlayerDialog(playerid, DIALOG_SELECT, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX,"Object Action", \
    "Select action for the object\nYou can edit or delete it","Edit","Delete");
    SetPVarInt(playerid, "SelectedObject", objectid);
    SetPVarInt(playerid, "ModelID", modelid);
    return 1;
}

public OnPlayerEditObject(playerid, playerobject, objectid, response, Float:fX, Float:fY, Float:fZ, Float:fRotX, Float:fRotY, Float:fRotZ)
{
    if(response == 1)
    {
        ShowPlayerDialog(playerid, DIALOG_SAVE_1, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX, "Object Edited",\
        "Do you want to save the object to a file?\n\nThe file with objects is located in {FFFFFF}scriptfiles/soe/*.txt",\
        "Save...","Cancel");
        O[foX] = fX;
        O[foY] = fY;
        O[foZ] = fZ;
        O[roX] = fRotX;
        O[roY] = fRotY;
        O[roZ] = fRotZ;
    }
}
```